# <svg> mask not working when used to display an svg <image> in react.js

Tags: jquery, css, svg, reactjs, mask

I am trying to get an image to appear above a background image when you mouseover it like this... https://jsfiddle.net/12zqhqod/7/

```
  <img id="heretic" height="300px" width="300px" src="http://i.imgur.com/0bKGVYB.jpg" />
<div class="pic">
  <svg class="blur" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mask id="mask1">
      <circle cx="-50%" cy="-50%" r="40" fill="white" />
    </mask>
    <image mask="url(#mask1)" id="bird" alt="follow me" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/IGKVr8r.png" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```

and the javascript...

```
 var mask1 = $('#mask1 circle')[0];
$('.pic').mousemove(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var upX = event.clientX;
  var upY = event.clientY;
  console.log(upX, upY);
  mask1.setAttribute("cy", (upY - 5) + 'px');
  mask1.setAttribute("cx", (upX) + 'px');
});
```

but I cannot seem to get it to work in react.js it just comes out like this... https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/32320/

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

and the react.js javascript...

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
                    <img id="heretic" height="300px" width="300px" src="http://i.imgur.com/0bKGVYB.jpg" />

    <div className="pic">
        <svg className="layers" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mask id="mask1">
            <circle cx="-50%" cy="-50%" r="40" fill="white" />
        </mask>
        <image className="imageTest" mask="url(#mask1)" alt="follow me" xlinkHref="http://i.imgur.com/IGKVr8r.png" width="100%" height="100%"></image>

            </svg>
     </div>
   </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);

var mask1 = $('#mask1 circle')[0];
$('.pic').mousemove(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var upX = event.clientX;
  var upY = event.clientY;
  console.log(upX, upY);
  mask1.setAttribute("cy", (upY - 5) + 'px');
  mask1.setAttribute("cx", (upX) + 'px');
});
```

I have tried setting the mask attribute manually by using setAttribute in componentDidMount, but then the `<image>` disappears and will not show up when mouseovered. It appears that the mask circle doesn't leave (0,0), but watching the elements tab in the dev options of my browser shows the cx and cy attributes updating correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: here is the fiddle for after I moved the javascript to componentDidMount...  https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/32321/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you missed the styles. Just adding the styles similar of those in your original fiddle:

```
.pic {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elrumordelaluz/530hLe9c/2/).